# Selective model lib

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, crate

how can i have crate that depend on with feature use another version of same crate like below

```
[features]
serde_1 = ["dep_serde_1"]
serde_1_0_133 = ["dep_serde_1_0_133"]

[dependencies]
dep_serde_1 = { package = "serde", version = "1.0.0", optional = true}
dep_serde_1_0_133 = { package = "serde", version = "1.0.133", optional = true}
```

my problem is compiler force me to use

```rust
use dep_serde_1::*;
```

except like this

```rust
use serde::*;
```

i just enable one of them at time and in code with `cfg(feature = serde_1)`  i'll chose what code must compile

sorry about my poor English

### [Edit]

main idea drive form this problem, for example
if my model use actix-0.10 and another crate that use my lib use actix-0.12 it generate compiler error

Comment: And what should happen if someone depending on your crate activates both features at once?

Comment: i don't want user can select both but it's just part of bigger service and we assume that user use just one of them

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Maybe you should try explaining the issue you are hoping to resolve in more detail rather than asking how to do what you think is a good solution (because it's not really).

Comment: Also, by "model" do you mean "module"?

Comment: assume a micro-service i wanna split service API models and web parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you want. If you want the name of the crate to be `serde` in your use statements, you can rename them back:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "dep_serde_1")]
extern crate dep_serde_1 as serde;
#[cfg(feature = "dep_serde_1_0_133")]
extern crate dep_serde_1_0_133 as serde;

// Now you can
use serde::*;
```

[Edit:] The above takes care of your use of serde, but `serde_derive` has its own ideas. When you define a struct like

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Asdf { /* … */ }
```

serde generates code that looks roughly like this:

```rust
const _: () = {
    extern crate serde as _serde;
    #[automatically_derived]
    impl _serde::Serialize for Asdf { /* …
```

i.e. it ignores the renaming of the serde crate and tries to use the crate by its original name.

You can override this behavior with the `crate` container attribute:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(crate = "serde")]
struct Asdf { /* … */ }
```

which will make the generated code use the serde from the outer namespace:

```rust
const _: () = {
    use serde as _serde;
    #[automatically_derived]
    impl serde::Serialize for Asdf {
```

---

Note, that mutually exclusive features are [not a good idea](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4328#issuecomment-652075026). If you can, it's better to make one the default and the other to override it.

I'm also not sure your cargo dependencies are actually doing what you want them to. Cargo doesn't allow depending on a crate twice, and if I force `dep_serde_1` to `=1.0.0` cargo will complain that there is a conflict.

Comment: thanks for your answer it's good but not working with derive macro
```#[derive(Serialize)]```
and generate error

Comment: @AliMirghasemi I edited the answer to explain how to handle that.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it, and yes i have default feature for serde but i want let user change version base on need

Comment: I think you're not achieving that, it seems your cargo.toml forces a version ≥1.0.133 no matter which features are selected. Just use a single dependency `serde = "1.0"`. Whatever uses your library can then add `serde` as a dependency itself and specify a precise version, or mess around with `cargo update --precise` to modify the lock file.

Comment: good point, i checked cargo ignore bug fix version ```1.0.x``` but if i have two different version like this ```serde = "1.0"``` and ```serde = "0.9"``` this code can work